# how to control rounding mode of real number in systemverilog

Tags: rounding, system-verilog, ieee-754

I would like to write a test for FPU module and can't find out a way to change a rounding mode of real numbers in SystemVerilog. Does the system function or any easy method exist to do that?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: which rounding mode you are interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change the rounding mode (away from 0). You can choose to truncate using the $rtoi function, or look at the bit patterns directly using $realtobits.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should send this out to a C environment via DPI, where you should be able to have more precise control over the rounding mode in use.